# How can I access to a folder as it was one on my own server but on a remote?

Tags: debian, samba, nfs, file-sharing, remote

I need to provide to an application data in folder but this folder is on remote server.

I know I can use NFS or SAMBA but I'm not a sysadmin, and I just know how to set up such mount point, as a client as well.

Is there any easy set up to "share" one folder and mount it remotly ?

Answer (score 0):

you can use the net share command to share the folder e.g. "NET SHARE MyShare=c:\shared-folder"

then on your other mahchine use the command net use e.g. "NET USE Z: \SERVERNAME\MyShare"

There are options such as /GRANT you can use on the net share command to set up permissions and /PERSISTENT on the net use command to keep the share set up between reboots

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer, my apologies however, I need it on debian/linux machines

Answer (score 0):

You can mount the remote directory with SSH. Places menu -> Connect to server -> select SSH and give the info needed (remote machine, user used to access the directory on the remote machine and password).

Answer (score 0):

One tool that you can try is [sshfs](http://packages.debian.org/squeeze/sshfs) (you can use this from the command line without needing a GUI).  You do not need to do any setup on the server side.  Connecting from the client is as simple as:

```
sshfs server.example.com:/path/to/source/ /path/to/dest/mount/
```